# Why does the Youtube iFrame API not detect state change

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have created a page with the following code to detect state changes to a YT iFrame embed. The player detects the `onReady` event but not the `onStageChange` event.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing here?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOZVoX?editors=1001

Code:

```
<iframe id="yt-iframe" width="630" height="354" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CTFtOOh47oo?rel=0&amp;?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.id = 'yt-iframe';
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    console.log('yt scripts loaded');
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('yt-iframe', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log('video player ready');
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        console.log('state has changed');
        console.log(event.data);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes on your code.

First of all your video url parameters are not correct.

Your url is `http://www.youtube.com/embed/CTFtOOh47oo?rel=0&amp;?enablejsapi=1`
, thus you pass the parameters `rel` and `amp;?enablejsapi`.

Instead your link should be `http://www.youtube.com/embed/CTFtOOh47oo?enablejsapi=1`, with the parameter `enablejsapi`.

Your second mistake is that you set your yt script's id to be the same with your iframe's id.

Change the id of the yt script to something else like `tag.id = 'yt-script';`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPJJbv?editors=0001